# Setting distance from label to node in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf

I drew a point using TikZ and labelled it 'P0'.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]

  \path (0,0) coordinate (P0) node[right]{P0};
  \fill (P0) circle (2pt);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Now, in the output, the label 'P0' is too close to the point itself. Is there a way to move it further from the point?

Comment: P0 is not a label, it's node containing only text. Tikz has a separate label attribute. Not to be picky, but could you remove the term "label" from this question? I'm trying to set the distance from a node to its label and it's unfortunately a completely different question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `right=<dimension>`

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]

  \path (0,0) coordinate (P0) node[right=2cm]{P0};
  \fill (P0) circle (2pt);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Do you know the default distance value ?